# which rshiny libraries use bootstrap v3

Tags: javascript, shiny

recent penetration test has revealed that some of my shiny apps use outdated javascripts libraries: Bootstrap 3.4.1, 3.4.5 and JQuery 1.12.1. Can you help me how can I find which libraries uses outdated js libs?
Issue is not very clear, because adding some r libraries "overwrite" bootstrap to newer version (>5).Perhaps there is some other approach to eliminate using oudated libs (rshiny server on Ubuntu).

Best regards
Tomasz